# presenting comma separated data from oracle into line by line inside a single cell of excel sheet using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i have data in  db which reads

> data=a,b,c,d

i need to export this data to excel file under a single cell using java which should read like this

> a
>
> b
>
> c
>
> d

i have done the exporting part but unable to bring the values like the above under a single cell. i have presently done this but its wrong.

```
   String Data=getDataVO.getData();

     String Data1[]=Data.split(",");

for(int i=0;i<=Data1.length;i++){

   String dt=Data1[i].concat(newline);
           ExcelUtil.setCell(row, ExcelConstants.ONE, dt, style);}
```

pls help.

Comment: which library do you use for writing to an Excel file? which package did you import for using ExcelUtil and ExcelConstants?

Comment: @KonstantinosChalkias apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell; and those are custom made Excel constants

Comment: It seems to have no importance that data comes from Oracle as far as can be seen. Should it then really be tagged Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to guess your scenario from the incomplete question. But you seem to be resetting the contents of the cell in every iteration of the for loop. Also your for loop limit condition is off-by-one, which will cause an index-out-of-bounds exception.

Try this instead:

```
String NEW_LINE = ...;

String data = getDataVO.getData();
String splitData[] = data.split(",");

String cellContents = "";
for(int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++)
{
    cellContents = cellContents.concat(splitData[i])
                               .concat(NEW_LINE);
}

ExcelUtil.setCell(row, ExcelConstants.ONE, cellContents, style);
```

If you have more elements, it might be more efficient to use a StringBuilder instead of a concat().

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i had conveyed the question improperly.

the code below satisfies my condition.

apache.poi.hssf. is what i used and the Excel constants are custom made.

pls feel free to make suggestions to improve my answer if alternates available.
`cellstyle.setWrapText(true);
    cell.setCellStyle(cellstyle);
    String Data=getDataVO.getData();
    data1=data.replaceAll(",","\n");
    ExcelUtil.setCell(row, ExcelConstants.ONE, data1, cellstyle);`

thank you.